# Rails: simple_format and class conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, loops

I'm trying to render some text in Rails with simple_format, but I want to add a class to any lines shorter than 100 characters. Is this at all achievable?

In my view I've:

```
<%= add_titles(simple_format(truncate(@a1b, :length => 1450))) %>
```

And in my controller I've this:

```
  def add_titles(a)
    for a.each_line do |b|
      if b.length < 100
        print(b, :class => 'strong')
      else
        print b
      end
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else stuck on this problem I've solved it by putting this logic into the pertinent views:

```
<% @article.body.each_line do |m| %>
  <% if m.length > 70 %>
    <%= content_tag(:p, m) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= content_tag(:h4, m) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```